# How to setup packet BBS?

Tags: packet

Here is my goal: To be able to talk to my friend using packet even when He or I are not there using a saving to TNC technique. We live only a few miles away from each other, and have a good signal.

I would love to be indicated when I have a message awaiting, therefore, I can get right to the terminal and reply.

I have the MFJ-1270B, and it has 5 LED lights on it DCD PTT STA CON PWR. I am assuming the STA light might have something to do with a message awaiting because it is the only one that hasn't been used yet.

Does the 1270B support BBS? If so, what commands would my friend use to send a message to me and SAVE it?

I want to do this as simply as possible, and just want to be able to Text over ham radio simple messages where we can have notifications (like the LED on the TNC) when we get a message directly to our calls.

I am giving my friend the PK232 and I know that one is capable of BBS and has an indicator light, but I just picked up the MFJ 1270B at the hamfest and don't know much about it.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see anything in the manual that would indicate the MFJ 1270B would support packet BBS natively. You would need some external hardware to do that.

You can find a scan of the manual online here:
http://www.repeater-builder.com/mfj/pdfs/mfj-1270b-tnc-manual.pdf

According to that doc, the STA LED "is normally low and goes high only when this TNC has unacknowledged packets in its transmit buffer."

Comment: Weird enough, typing mailbox actually setup a simple BBS, which was very strange because the command was not stated anywhere in the instructions

Comment: Cool stuff! Glad you found that; it must have been added in a revision after the doc on repeater-builder.com.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but there's a chance the mailbox commands for the 1270C would be the same: http://www.repeater-builder.com/mfj/pdfs/mfj-1270c-1274c-tnc-manual.pdf